# Public_Profile permission in Meta GraphAPI

Tags: facebook-graph-api, bigdata, sentiment-analysis

I have `Public_Profile` permission in Meta GraphAPI but I'm unable to Generate Access Token. Can someone help me?

I am hoping to fetch public posts using the API. I have a Researcher permission for the APP. I have `public_profile` permission but it shows `@This` feature is unavailable because this app is not approved for the `public_profile` permission when I try to Generate an access token.

Comment: _"I have a Researcher permission for the APP"_ - no idea what you are talking about there, there is no such thing as a "researcher" permission.

Comment: Does your user account have a _role_ in the app? If not, you will only be able to use it, after it has been submitted for review and has been made public.

Comment: What I meant was App type is Academic Research

Comment: Don't know what that is supposed to be either, that is not one of the available app types listed here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/app-types

Comment: There is an Academic Researcher App Type option available for me. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fort/get-access/academic-verif/

Comment: Says there that you need to have completed app review before this will work. And the error message sounds like you didn't ...?